# Android Studio won't mark problems anymore

Tags: android, android-studio

When I go in a file and it has obvious issues it won't underline the class in the left tree view of the project nor it will mark stuff in the file with red. What happened and any ideas on how to toggle this back ?!

Comment: Try cleaning up the project.

Comment: Well what was dumb. Wanna write it as the answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Build --> make project. if that doesn't work then post more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu, Got to `Build` -> `Clean Project`